# Where do I enter application arguments in XCode?

Tags: iphone

I am new to Objective C and iPhone development.  I am using CoreData on the new iPhone 3.0 platform.  My application executes; however, I am getting no objects back from the fetchedResultsController.  I would like to see the SQL that is being passed to SQLite.

In the Apple documentation it says I can see this by passing the following argument to the application

-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1

Where exactly do I do this at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In XCode editor on the left pane in the list of groups and files:

1) Expand the "Executables" group
2) Select your application executable and right click
3) Select Get Info
4) Select the Arguments tab
5) Add the necessary argument in the Arguments box

Answer (score 11):

In XCode 4 it works differently.

1. Click on the Schemes drop down list (between Stop and Breakpoints buttons at the top),
2. then choose Edit Scheme and choose your scheme,
3. then choose Run tab (on the left) and Arguments tab at the top,
4. Put the argument into "Arguments Passed on Launch"