# Why does CoreData Debug logging not work on my Mac app?

Tags: cocoa, xcode, debugging, core-data

I can't get Core Data debug logging working.

I've gone into the arguments tab of my executable in Xcode and added:

`-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1`

as per the documentation and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819028/where-do-i-enter-application-arguments-in-xcode). And yes, I am on the Mac [not on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822906/how-do-i-get-the-coredata-debug-argument-to-output-to-the-console).

**What I've Tried**

- Different compilers (LLVM 1.5 and GCC 4.2)
- Have all debug symbols included
- Building i386 instead of x84_64 architectures

**Download**

My Xcode project: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/136780/TransientDurationUpdateTest1.zip

Another project I have shows the SQL debug logs fine. What on earth am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it doesn't help that I set the store type to XML. What a numpty. As soon as I changed it back to SQLite all logging resumed perfectly.

Comment: Well, I was looking into ways to log CoreData errors, and found your question here, so that was in fact helpful. Thank you Google, thank you SO, and thank you John :-)

Comment: You're very welcome, Charles. I'm glad someone else has found SO as useful as I have! :)